# How to mock History in Angular jasmine testing?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I'm new in testing environment and Angular itself, I'm trying to write tests for a project that is already started.
Now I'm getting this error when I try to setup and run the test:
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'data')**

**create-organization.component.ts**

```
export class CreateOrganizationComponent implements OnInit {
  summaryFormValues: any = {};

  tabConfig!: TabStepperModel[];

  organizationData: any;

  constructor(
    private territoryService: TerritoryService,
    private organizationService: OrganizationService,
    private countryListService: CountryHelperService,
    private navService: NavigationService,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private journeyService: JourneyService,
    private spinnerService: SpinnerService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.journeyService.clearData()
    const historyState = history.state.data ? history.state.data.data : null;
    if (historyState) {
      const createOrganizationData: CreateOrganizationModel = {
        basic: historyState.data.basic,
        organizationalContact: historyState.data.organizationalContact,
        extraDetails: historyState.data.extraDetails,
      };
      const journeyData = { ...createOrganizationData, isEdit: true };
      this.journeyService.setData(journeyData);
    }
  }
}
```

**create-organization.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { getJourneyServiceSpyObj } from '../../../../common/testing/services/journey.service.test';
import { getTerritoryServiceSpyObj } from '../../../../common/testing/services/territory.service.test';
import { getNavigationServiceSpyObj } from '../../../../common/testing/services/navigation.service.test';
import { getSpinnerServiceSpyObj } from '../../../../common/testing/services/spinner.service.test';
import { TerritoryService } from '../../../cipfa-template/services/territory.service';
import { JourneyService } from '../../../shared/services/journey.service';
import { NavigationService } from '../../../shared/services/navigation.service';
import { SpinnerService } from '../../../shared/services/spinner.service';
import { getHttpClientSpyObj } from 'apps/client/src/app/common/testing/angular/http-client.test';

import { CreateOrganizationComponent } from './create-organization.component';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

fdescribe('CreateOrganizationComponent', () => {
  let component: CreateOrganizationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CreateOrganizationComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [CreateOrganizationComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: NavigationService, useValue: getNavigationServiceSpyObj() },
        { provide: SpinnerService, useValue: getSpinnerServiceSpyObj() },
        { provide: JourneyService, useValue: getJourneyServiceSpyObj() },
        { provide: TerritoryService, useValue: getTerritoryServiceSpyObj() },
        { provide: HttpClient, useValue: getHttpClientSpyObj() },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateOrganizationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Where is `history`? What is `history`? Is it a global object?

Comment: yes it's global object